# Is Go language CPU dependent?

Tags: go, cpu, cpu-architecture

Is Go language CPU dependent?

I know it supports x86, x86_64 and ARM. Does it have some CPU depend code like assembler code blocks?

**PS** I was not clear enough. Does Go language implementation is CPU dependent?

I do not wish to add ARM assembly code in my program. I am wondering if Go program could be compiled on x86(_64) and ARM only and all other platforms are not supported.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by CPU-dependent. There are at least two Go compilers in existence (Google and GNU) with varying platform support. The language itself is portable, with few assumptions made about the CPU.

Comment: The `int` type can be 64/32 bits wide. Or were you talking about functions written in assembly for efficiency (like RC4)? Could you make an example of what you mean by CPU dependence?

Comment: I do not know if Go is CPU dependent. Go site tells that Go only works on x86(_64) and ARM. Why? I wish to write proxy server for ddwrt router. It has MIPSEL CPU.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go is compiled, so the end result is indeed (CPU-specific) machine code.

```
$ echo 'package main\nfunc main(){ println("hello world") }' > hello.go
$ go build hello.go
$ objdump -D hello | head

hello:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048c00 <main.main>:
 8048c00:   65 8b 0d 00 00 00 00    mov    %gs:0x0,%ecx
 8048c07:   8b 49 f8                mov    -0x8(%ecx),%ecx
 8048c0a:   3b 21                   cmp    (%ecx),%esp
```

So you won't be able to just take executable compiled for, say, ARM, and run it on x86.

Despite that, Go has [excellent support for cross-compiling](http://www.goinggo.net/2013/10/cross-compile-your-go-programs.html) programs for different OSes and architectures, so in most cases you won't need a bunch of machines (virtual or real) running different OSes to compile your programs for those targets.

Comment: It mentions x86 and ARM but there are many other platforms. I understand that if I compile for ARM then it will on ARM. But it means Go will not run on MIPS or MIPSEL or PowerPC

Comment: The link you gave mentions: openbsd and plan9 operating sytems that are not nentioned on official page (Windows/FreeBSD/Linux/MacOSX)

Comment: The official website [does mention Plan 9 and OpenBSD](http://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment). While the `go` toolchain does not support MIPS or PowerPC, it seems that those architectures [are supported by gccgo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/dkzGY-4OgJw).